# QScrollArea transparent background on MacOS X

Tags: c++, macos, qt, stylesheet

I have a problem with making contents of `QScrollArea` to not draw a background.

So here is the initial picture, when I apply no stylesheet:
[image]
You can see, that the contents of scroll area are darker then the overall frame.

I have found the stylesheet that I can apply to scroll area, so the background is transparent. Here's the stylesheet I use:

```
QScrollArea { background: transparent; }
QScrollArea > QWidget > QWidget { background: transparent; }
```

Problem is that when I do that, the scrollbar of scrollarea gets messed up:
[image]

You see? The scrollbar is now always visible and is ugly and transparent.

How can I make my stylesheet not to affect the scrollbar, while still applying it to the `QScrollArea`? Or what different stylesheet should I apply instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try to set an object name for the scroll area viewport:

```
pScrollArea->viewport()->setObjectName("myViewport");
```

then address it using the hashtag property in the stylesheet (also add the groupbox since the way I see it in your screenshot, your goal is to make them transparent as well):

```
QScrollArea, #myViewport, QGroupBox { 
  background: transparent;
}
```

Comment: It wasn't really about defining QGroupBox background (which didn't work and even broke the fonts of groupbox), but when I used #hashtag_named selector and I've applied transparent background to scrollarea and scrollcontents widget, then it works as expected. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that QScrollBar is a subclass of QWidget, so just target the viewport with that rule:

```
pScrollArea->setStyleSheet("QScrollArea { background: transparent; }");
pScrollArea->viewport()->setStyleSheet(".QWidget { background: transparent; }");
```

Notice the dot before QWidget, so to not target any children of the viewport (i.e., any viewport content that's a QWidget subclass).