# QScrollArea clears background color

Tags: qt, qscrollarea, qt5.3

In my qss style sheet I define a background color

```
#sw_MainMiddle {
    background: black;
}
```

Everything fine, but when I place a scroll `QScrollArea` in the `sw_MainMiddle` widget, the background color is gone. Obviously there is no chance to assign a background directly to `QScrollArea`. Below code has no effect:

```
QScrollArea {
    background: black;
}
```

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25795112/qscrollarea-transparent-background-on-macos-x) I have used object name selector to re-assign the background color to the scroll area, no effect too:

```
#myScrollArea {
    background: black;
}
```

Anything I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think I found the solution:

```
QAbstractScrollArea #scrollAreaWidgetContents {
    background-color: black;
}
```

where `scrollAreaWidgetContents` is the widget inside the scroll area:

[image]

From the [QSS Reference Page](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/stylesheet-reference.html):

> All derivatives of QAbstractScrollArea, including QTextEdit, and
>   QAbstractItemView (all item view classes), support scrollable
>   backgrounds using background-attachment. Setting the
>   background-attachment to fixed provides a background-image that does
>   not scroll with the viewport. Setting the background-attachment to
>   scroll, scrolls the background-image when the scroll bars move.
>
> See [Customizing QAbstractScrollArea](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qabstractscrollarea) for an example.

So you can't customize let's say all `QAbstractScrollArea`s or all `QScrollArea`s, only the widgets containing them(e.g. `QTextEdit`). That's why `QScrollArea { background-color: black; }` doesn't work. However if you want to customize *particular* widgets containing scroll area this solution should be sufficient.